# About C++ priority_queue what does vector<int> do in priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int> > pq?

Tags: c++

To construct a priority_queue in c++

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int> > pq
```

int is the type of value the queue stores, greater is the comparator what does the second argument

```
vector<int>
```

do here?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter is the underlying container that the queue uses.

The `priority_queue` template is a *container adaptor*. That is, it doesn't provide dynamic storage itself, but rather, it *adapts* an existing container to provide the desired interface.

(The interface for a priority queue is implemented in terms of the `make_heap`/`push_heap`/`pop_heap` algorithms from the standard library, and the underlying container needs to have suitable iterators.)